# Cannot attach database to MVC project

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

In my MVC project I am unable to attach the instance of a local database to the project. So after i run into this situation specifiied in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34812158/5243291) question, I tried to attach the local database manually by adding a connection in the Data connections. But it gives me the following error.

[image: screenshot]

What is the right approach to add the databse to my project so that I could execute the program without any database errors?

The project was executing properly before I moved the project to another location. Now I have again moved the project back to the old location.

Comment: In what version of SQL server is the database created? The first error indicates that you have installed an earlier version of sql-server.

Comment: I am using Sql-Server express 2012. I had it working before i changed my project location.

Comment: But i have solved the issue; it was because i was not having the database in my App-Data folder. I copied the database to the App-Data folder and it worked.